# Как избавиться от pyCharm'a в Ubuntu?

Tags: python, pycharm, ubuntu

Добрый день!

Как бы я не пытался найти его через synaptic, центр приложений , sudo apt-get remove --purge pycharm тоже не проходит. Кто-нибудь знает, как его удалить?

Comment: А как вы его ставили? Не помню, чтоб у них были deb-пакеты.

Comment: Отсюда https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/ скачал. Файл pycharm-community-4.0.4.tar.gz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто удалите директорию, куда его распаковывали и возможно линк на скрипт запуска.

Comment: Директорию я найду, а вот линк на запуск ...?

Comment: А где вы его видите? В launch панели или на рабочем столе? Если ни там и ни там - значит его вообще нет. К тому же он весит десяток байт, не волнуйтесь по поводу него )

Comment: Ostrovski, спасибо.

Comment: @Ostrovski, если вас беспокоит иконка PyCharm'а в меню, то можете удалить соответствующий .desktop-файл из директории `/usr/share/applications/`